# How to use ogr2ogr to reproject shapefile in Python

Tags: gdal, ogr, osgeo4w

I am trying to reproject the coordinate system of a shapefile.

I know I can do it in the OSGEO4W window as `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs EPSG:3857 C:/test/input.shp C:/test/output.tif`

However, I want to be able to do this in Python. I found this documentation but can't figure out how to achieve what I want

https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-a-new-shapefile-and-add-data

Comment: You are using `output.tif` instead of `output.shp` so it's not clear if you want to transform a shp to tiff or just reproject a shapefile, or both. Please clarify your question. Also if GDAL python bindings ir the only library you are allowed to use or other python libraries can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do: transform the epsg or convert the file shp to tif or both?

for changing the projection of a shape, I use

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" two.shp one.shp -s_srs EPSG:2154 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
```

if you want to rasterize, it seems to me that it is necessary to use `gdal_rasterize...`